# How I get a set of Values in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of values in html from 1 to 19 but aren`t ordened.
So I dont know how I can get these values in javascript.

```
<ol id="cities" class="example">   
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">city a</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="8">city b</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="9">city c</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="12">city d</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="14">city e</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="16">city f </li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="18">Seguro g</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="19">city h</li>
</ol>
```

then I would like receive all values for I can work with it.
var cities = 2,8,9,12,14,16,18,19
 I have trying some kind of code to show but I have erased because doesnt works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've also tagged jquery, you can use `.map` http://api.jquery.com/map/

```js
var values = $("#cities>li").map(function() { 
                     return $(this).attr("value"); 
                 })
                 .toArray();

console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="cities" class="example">   
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">city a</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="8">city b</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="9">city c</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="12">city d</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="14">city e</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="16">city f </li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="18">Seguro g</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="19">city h</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: excellent answer, this solve my problem. array.map was the solution

Answer (score 1):

Very easy. Take a look:

```js
var values = [];
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(e=>values.push(e.value));
console.log(values);
```

```html
<ol id="cities" class="example">   
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">city a</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="8">city b</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="9">city c</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="12">city d</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="14">city e</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="16">city f </li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="18">Seguro g</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="19">city h</li>
</ol>
```

Explanation:

`var values = []` => this is an array where the values will be populated.

`document.querySelectorAll('li')` => this selects all `li` elements.

`forEach(` => this loops all elements selected calling a function for each element

`e=>values.push(e.value)` => this is a function that pushes each element 
                             to the the values array and it's equivalent to:

```
 function(e) {
     values.push(e.value);
 }
```

you can even reduce it further:

```js
var values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).map(e=>e.value);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<ol id="cities" class="example">   
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">city a</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="8">city b</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="9">city c</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="12">city d</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="14">city e</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="16">city f </li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="18">Seguro g</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" value="19">city h</li>
</ol>
```

If you want a jQuery version just substitute document.querySelectorAll for $. In this case you won't need `Array.from(` anymore since jQuery result object already has map method in it.

**Edit**

Based in your comment, just substitute `e=>values.push(e.value)` by `e=>{ if (e.value) values.push(e.value); }` and you will exclude the 0 values from the result array.

Comment: thanks, this is a good answer but I had 114 extra values with zero inside.